# How to post data using api on a link of php site

Tags: php, asp.net

I have developed a web site in asp.net where user can register him/her self now other developers require this data in json format only.
Problem is another developer using PHP and I am using asp.net so how to send data in json format using PHP site link.
Other developer said he will share a link then I will call this link in API to send the data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm as php programmer. For me, I recommended to transfer using JS array which it is better way from my experience cuz of the php has other disabilities.

So, you need to convert to array first. Please see official documentation.

Comment: can you please guide more as i have to share only email id. Now the problem is on every click of asp.net web form submit button i have to share the single email id to other developer. Php developer will save that particulate email id in his database so that he will use it later.